# kal delegate issue

Tags: ios, delegates, calendar

I think setting the delegate for the KalViewController correctly - copying both the Holiday & NativeCal demo - but I must not be because I'm getting the following error when I click upon a date cell:

```
-[UINavigationButton didSelectDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When I set breakpoints on All Exceptions I see that it's raising an exception in KalGridView.m in this function:

```
- (void)setSelectedTile:(KalTileView *)tile
{
  if (selectedTile != tile) {
    selectedTile.selected = NO;
    selectedTile = [tile retain];
    tile.selected = YES;
    [delegate didSelectDate:tile.date]; // exception raised here
  }
}
```

And here's the code where I set the delegate (pretty much copied from the demo code):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    calendar.delegate = self;
    [[self.view viewWithTag:1] addSubview:calendar.view];
....}
```

The error makes sense because I'm setting the delegate to my own ViewController which doesn't implement didSelectDate.  On the other hand, neither does the Holiday and NativeCal classes which are set at the KalViewController's delegate, both of which are of type

```
NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Thanks a pile.. I'm more than a touch stuck.

Comment: Your delegate is being released (or assigned improperly), and replaced by a different instance.  Override `-setDelegate:` and Call `-retain` on it.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are setting the delegate?

Comment: I just edited the question to show more sample code and explain a bit more.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm assuming that you're suggesting that I should override `setDelegate:` in KalViewController.  Is that really where the problem is?  Shouldn't I leave the library alone?

Comment: @CodaFi - I checked (using `po` in the `lldb`) and yes indeed, the delegate is different than what it was set to.  While I don't have the exact answer, I know where to look so thanks.  Maybe make your comment and answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: No problem.  Give me a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those rare instances where the delegate should probably be retained because it's being released and replaced.  Override `-setDelegate:` and retain your delegate.

Comment: Kinda.  It was indeed a delegate issue.  But it was that `calendar` was being created in viewDidLoad and then vanished when viewDidLoad finished.  It was the same code as the `Holiday` sample app, but there they do the call in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching in the AppDelegate which, I assume, never loses scope (I hope I have my terms right).